# HTML and PHP, filling a dropdown with lines from file

Tags: php, html, file

I have a file which currently contains

```
C41234
B36355
B41234
```

and I can't seem to find a way to read these from the file and then add each to my dropdown. The contents of the file are subject to change so I need to use a variable of some sort. I'm using php to read my file. I took a shot in the dark and tried

```
    $j= 0;
echo'<b>Choose the reservation you would like to change </b>';
echo'<p>';
echo'<select name="change">';

while (!feof($fp)) 
{
 echo'<option> $reservations[$j]</option>';
 $j++;
}
echo '</select>';
```

where $reservations[] already contains the file contents. it's echoing the html just fine, i'm just not filling the dropdown correctly.
any help is much appreciated!

Comment: How does $reservations[] relate to $fp?  If $reservations[] contains the content you need, shouldn't you be iterating over it?

Comment: im filling $reservations[] by reading in each file from $fp = "myfile"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$fp = fopen("reservations.txt", "r");

echo '<b>Choose the reservation you would like to change </b>';
echo '<p>';
echo '<select name="change">';

while(!feof($fp)){
    $line = trim(fgets($fp));
    echo "<option>{$line}</option>";
}

fclose($fp);
echo '</select>';
```

Hope this code helps you!

Comment: wonderful, thanks! outputting just the line rather than the array should have been more obvious to me

Answer (score 0):

If `$reservations` already looks like this...

```
array(3) {
    [0] =>
    string(6) "C41234"
    [1] =>
    string(6) "B36355"
    [2] =>
    string(6) "B41234"
}
```

Then all you need to do is loop through the `$reservations` array...

```
foreach ($reservations as $res) {
    echo "<option>$res</option>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing you'll want to do is build your reservations array:

```
$reservations = file("my_reservations.txt");
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php

Then loop through that array and echo your options:

```
<select>
    <?php 
        for ($i=0; $i < count($reservations); $i++) { 
            echo "<option>" . $reservations[$i] . "</option>";
        }
     ?>
</select>
```